# Why function variable (when logged in console) does not show the whole function body?

Tags: javascript, tostring, console.log

I would like to know why function variable (when logged in console) does not show the whole function body but toString() method does.

```
function person(name) {
    this.f_name = name;

    return function print_name (){
            alert("Your Name Is: " + this.f_name);
        }
  }

var myfunc = person('James');

  console.log(myfunc); //-> function print_name()

  console.log(myfunc.toString()); // ->"function print_name(){
        alert("Your Name Is: " + this.f_name);
    }"
```

Comment: Because that's explicitly what `toString` does, and that's *not* explicitly what the console does...!?

Comment: What browser and version are you using? `console` implementations vary a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything you `console.log` that can't just be printed gets it's respective `toString` method called to *still* be able to represent / summary the *most important* details about the function.

As you can read here: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/toString) - and specifically this quote:

> the toString method returns a string representation of the object in
>   the form of a function declaration. That is, toString decompiles the
>   function, and the string returned includes the function keyword, the
>   argument list, curly braces, and *the source of the function body <sup>[1]</sup>*.

This basically says you don't need to know the internals to debug since you can look at the source for that (either in the devtools or in your editor) so it doesn't bother printing everything - just that which is required / convenient for the programmer to know at that time.

[1] - I don't actually know why this line is there or I'm misunderstanding. *(As pointed out by [@deceze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/476/deceze) in the comments below)*

I ran the following code in the dev tools of some browsers to compare:

`console.log(function(a, b) { return a + b; });`

Output:

- Firefox: `function ()` - w/o arguments but clickable to see more info
- Chrome: `function (a, b) { return a + b }` w/ arguments, clicking it takes you to a pane in the devtools with the source of the function
- Safari: `function (a, b) { return a + b; }`, w/ arguments, clicking does nothing

As I'm on a Mac I can't test this in IE but the outputs are interesting.
It's more of a developer's preference as to which browser he/she develops in since this is just a dev API and not something that should be consistent cross-browser.

Comment: You're saying the console should call `.toString` which should contain the function body, yet that's exactly *not* what happens...!?

Comment: @deceze thanks for pointing it out, seems there's either a fault in the docs or we're misunderstanding *'the source of the function body'*

Comment: Hi, I tried the above in Chrome and yes `console.log(myfunc)` output the whole func definition unlike Firefox. I doubted my understanding that I was missing a point in understanding JS (I'm a beginner) but turns out that it's the browsers console that was causing the confusion. Next time I'm going to use `alert()` for test outputs which I believe is cross-browser.

Comment: @sapnakoramagiri `alert()` and `console.log()` serve very different purposes, if you have a big data structure (object with lots of nested objects or arrays or w/e) then `console.log()` supersedes `alert()` in any and every way, just try them both out and see what works best. I personally find `alert()`ing annoying as it shows text in a browser prompt which you have to click away, `console.log()` just logs to a console and if you forget to remove one it doesn't pop up accidentally on a live website ^.^